# Can I get the values used to construct a Python 2.7 xrange from the object itself?

Tags: python, python-2.7, range, introspection, xrange

If `s` is a `slice` object in Python, constructed using either `s = slice(start, stop, step)` or (in the appropriate context) `start:stop:step`, the values used to construct `s` are available from the `slice` object itself as `s.start`, `s.stop` and `s.step`.

Similar `start`, `stop` and `step` members are available on `range` objects in Python 3.4 [[Issue9896](http://bugs.python.org/issue9896)]. For example, `range(1, 4, 2).start == 1`.

However, Python 2.7 `xrange` objects do not have the `start`, `stop` and `step` members. Is there any other way to obtain the values used to construct the `xrange` from the object itself?

Comment: You can pretty easily get values that would construct an equivalent range, but not the actual constructor arguments used.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to recover the original `start` and `step` arguments, but not always the original `stop` argument.

One way you can get the values is to look at the `__reduce__` (or `__reduce_ex__`) method of the `xrange` object (normally used for pickling):

```
>>> x = xrange(10)
>>> x.__reduce__()[1]
(0, 10, 1)
>>> y = xrange(2, 100, 13)
>>> y.__reduce__()[1]
(2, 106, 13)
```

Then `start, stop, step = y.__reduce__()[1]` would assign the three variable names to the appropriate integers. The `start` and `step` values are always the original values that were used to construct the `xrange` object.

`stop` may be higher that the argument originally used to contract the object. For any `xrange` object `x` it is equal to `x[-1] + step`.

In general, it is not possible to recover the original stop argument once the `xrange` object has been created. If you study the [source for `xrange`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3cf2990d19ab/Objects/rangeobject.c#l65), you'll see that this object does not keep a reference to a particular stop value, only the starting value, step value and overall length of the iterator. When `str` or `__reduce__` is called, the object will calculate the latest possible stop value with the internal function `get_stop_for_range`.

This is in contrast to Python 3's `range` object, which *does* remember the original [stop value](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c9239543235e/Objects/rangeobject.c#l67).

Answer (score 3):

It's not pretty, but you could parse the `str` representation of the `xrange`

```
>>> rr = xrange(1, 4, 2)
>>> str(rr)
'xrange(1, 5, 2)'
>>> start = str(rr).split('(')[1].split(',')[0]
>>> start
1
```

etc

Note that the `max` cannot reliably be found this way if there are steps specified in the range.  For example, in the example above, `(1, 4, 2)` becomes `(1, 5, 2)` in the `str` representation.